# Rank of this function

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

An excerpt from my Manifolds notes:

> Let $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^{2}}, t \mapsto (t^2 , t^{3}-t).$
> The Jacobian $DF|_{t}=(2t, 3t^{2}-1)$. So $DF|_{t} \ne 0$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. rank of $F$ is $1$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $F$ is an immersion.

**My questions:**

1. Why does $DF|_{t} \ne 0$ imply the rank of  $F$ is $1$ for any $t$?
2. Surely we have two linearly independent columns in our Jacobian here? Shouldn't the rank therefore be 2?

**My thoughts:**
The rank of $F$ is precisely the number of linearly independent columns of the Jacobian. Here, we have two columns. It seems to me that they are linearly independent (why would $2t$ and $3t^{2}-1$ not be?) so I would say the rank is two. This is apparently wrong.

Advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The rank of $F$ can not be higher than $1$ since $F$ is a smooth map from a $1$-dim manifold to a $2$-dim. manifold and rank$ F \le \min (1,2) = 1$. Thus if rank $F\not=0$, then rank $F = 1$.

Comment: @Zest got it, thank you!